# Formula to copy a cell from another worksheet where the name of worksheet to be copied from varies

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a workbook with a worksheet containing the following:
[Destination Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkhpq.jpg)

The data in cells B1, C1, D1 need to be equal to the value of cells A1, A2, A3 in a worksheet in same workbook named DOD11.2 (i.e. the name of the worksheet is the same as the letters up to the character x in the string in cells A1, A2, A3, A4)

The data in cells B2, C2, D2 are to be made equal to the value of cells B1, B2, B3 in the same DOD11.2 worksheet. Similarly, cells B3, C3, D3 are to equal the value of cells C1, C2, C3 in DOD11.2 and cells B4, C4, D4 are equal to value of D1, D2, D3 in DOD11.2.

This sequence then needs to be repeated for cells B6, C6, D6; B7, C7, D7 etc only this time their value needs to be equal to data in cells A1, A2, A3; B1, B2, B3 etc in the sheet named DOD12.2 (i.e the name of the worksheet is now the same as the letters up to the character x in the string in cells A6, A7, A8, A9)

Would appreciate any suggestions for a formula that I can use in cell B1 that can then be copied into the other cells and will correctly refer to the appropriate source worksheet and cells.

Thanks for your suggestion. I understand how you are using the CHAR funtion along with current cell row and column values to calculate the source cell values.  Unfortunately,  to make the query simpler to understand, I didn't give the complete story in my original post so your suggestion doesn't completely solve my problem.  The actual destination sheet looks like this[Actual destination Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqCee.jpg)  where the cell numbers shown (AD8, BM8..., AD9, BM9 etc) are the real cells addresses that need to be retrieved from the source sheet.  Also I have about 70 rows in the destination sheet that I need to assign the formula to. Any further suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indirect function and assemble a string containing the cell address.

Assuming you have the name of the file in `E7`, the name of the sheet within that file in `E9` and the name of the cell in `E11`, use the formula

```
=INDIRECT("'["&E7&"]"&E9&"'!"&E11)
```

In your particular case you are accessing sheets in the same file, so the formula becomes

```
=INDIRECT("E9&"!"&E11)
```

the name of the sheet in cell A1 is =left(A1,7)

cells in row 1 are from column A of that sheet
cells in row 2 are from cloumn B of that sheet etc.
so column name is char(64+<row number of cell>)

cells in column B are from row 1
cells in column C are from row 2 etc
so row number is <column number>-1

all this gives us the following formula to copy into B1, then fill right and down

```
=INDIRECT(left($a1,7)&"!"&char(row()+64)&column()-1)
```

this breaks if you have more than 26 lines.